# jQuery keydown/keypress not working right

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I haven an input:

```
<input type="text" name="in" />
```

And I need to get the current `value` of the input as I type, the problem that I face is, if I type `pass` and I do a console.log what I will get will be `pas` missing the last character; but I need to whole string `pass`

You can see a live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/HjVHV/1/ What's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `keyup` event:

```
$('input[name=in]').keyup(function()
{
  // $(this).val()
});
```

Inside you get the value you've just entered

Answer (score 4):

you should use  `keyup` :

```
$('input').keyup(function(){...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could keep up using `.keydown()` if you want, just append the character pressed using `.fromCharCode()` , like this:

```
$('input').keydown(function(e){
    $('.output').html($('input').val() + String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase());
});
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/HjVHV/8/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the key up event.

Here is the sample code based on your js fiddle

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    $('.output').html($('input').val());
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/qr59c/1/

I copied and modified the following block of code from http://forum.jquery.com/topic/can-change-handle-immediate-text-changes#14737000000967875

```
$('#input').each(function() {
 // Save current value of element
 $(this).data('oldVal', $(this));

 // Look for changes in the value
 $(this).bind("propertychange keyup input paste", function(event){
    // If value has changed...
    if ($(this).data('oldVal') != $(this).val()) {
     // Updated stored value
     $(this).data('oldVal', $(this).val());

     // Do action
     $('.output').html($('#input').val());
    }
 });
});
```